# drupal open id - how to get details

Tags: drupal, openid

I'm try to use drupal open id module. When i used to login using any provider id(yahoo,google,facebook..) it goes to registration page of my site. My question is **how to** ***populate details of the user to my form* without additional burden to the user** ?. For ex name,email-id etc. Is there any module associated with it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but this module sounds like it does what you want:

http://drupalmodules.com/module/openid-autoregistration

> "Module allows automatic registration of (successfully logged in) OpenID users, even in case OpenID provider didn't supply data necessary for Drupal user registration (valid username and email)".